# add a class to the body of another page by clicking on a link?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to use jquery so that when you click on a link, it goes to another page and add a class to the body tag of the new page.

of course the new page should open in the same window (not in a new window).

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: no but just give it a try...just send class name from querystring and get that querystring value from url on next page and set that class to ur element and style that class on ur new page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this , but in both cases you should own the new page that you want to open

### First solution

first solution is to make an indication someware, like an anchor for example and in the new page you look for the anchor, if it exists you add the class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  if(hash =="indication")
    $("body").addClass("class_to_add");
});
```

if the two pages are in the same domain, you can use the cookies as indication. you use a library like [this one](https://github.com/khaliid/happy-cookies.js) for example to add a cookie and to get the cookie in the other page

```
// in first page
 $.setCookie("indication","value"); 

// in second page
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($.getCookie("indication") =="value")
    $("body").addClass("class_to_add");
});
```

### Second solution

The second solution is to use iframe, once you click on a link you change the body of your page to an `iframe` `100% width` and `100% height` and then you can add the class to the page inside the iframe by the page outside like this

```
$("iframe").contents().find("body").addClass("class_to_add")
```

Comment: thank you very much @Khalid. I used your first solution and it worked. you're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's sort of possible, but not as simply as you want. Your javascript cannot modify the DOM of a page that has not yet been loaded, and once it has loaded the javascript you've called no longer exists.

What you COULD do would be to set some kind of flag somewhere, either as a query string in the URL, or as a cookie variable or web storage variable. Then on the load of the next page, check for the existence of this flag, and if present add the class that you want.

Other than this there's no way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, basically you'll have to persist the flag or class name when you move to next page. Webstorage is one way but the quickest can be by using URL.

Here's the sample : it uses hash params :

**Calling html page :**

```
<a href="new.html#myclass1">Apply .myclass1 to body</a>
<a href="new.html#myclass2">Apply .myclass2 to body</a>
```

**Called html page**

```
$(function(){
   var hash = $(location).attr('hash');
   $('body').addClass(hash);
});
```